# Output html conditional based on comments in blog post

Tags: html

I'm trying to only output the heading "Comments" when there are actually comments for a blog post.

Here's what I have:

```
{if total_comments >= 1}<h3>Comments</h3>{/if}
{exp:comment:entries sort="asc" limit="20"}
    <div class="text-block">
        <p>{comment}</p>
        <p id="author">By {name} on {current_time format="%F %d %Y"}</p>
    <hr>
    </div>
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before closing the Channel Entries tag, you can use the [comment_total variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#comment-total). Or if that does not work with your markup, you can use count conditionals in the Comment Entries tag (not nested inside your Channel Entries tag):

```
{exp:comment:entries sort="asc" limit="20"}
    {if count == 1}<h3>Comments</h3>{/if}
    <div class="text-block">
        <p>{comment}</p>
        <p id="author">By {name} on {current_time format="%F %d %Y"}</p>
    <hr>
    </div>
{/exp:comment:entries}
```